# Wso2 api manager + Twitter Integration

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I want to integrate my wso2 api manger with twitter account.
May i know how to do this. My api should be login with authenticate twitter credentials. Could you any one help me.

Thanks,

Raju K

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with apimanager + identity server. This blog[1] describes about how to access api using facebook authentication where facebook is configured as IDP in identity server. Similarly you can configure twitter as IDP in IS and achieve your requirement. IS has twitter connector[2] to add twitter authenticate.

[1] http://nuwanzone.blogspot.com/2015/10/getting-access-tokens-for-wso2-api.html
[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ISCONNECTORS/Configuring+Twitter+Authenticator

Comment: Thank you so much Jenananthan.